# ORA-02070: database does not support antijoin in this context

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I don't think this is even a question, but in case someone has seen something like this before or has any thoughts besides 'file a bug with Oracle' (which I'm doing), I'd love to hear it.

```
create table pat (patientid VARCHAR2(32), pcpid VARCHAR2(32), bval1 NUMBER(1), bval2 NUMBER(1));
create table tab (setmemberid VARCHAR2(32), uuid VARCHAR2(32));


SELECT COUNT(patientId) n FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT pat.patientId, pat.bval1, pat.bval2
FROM pat
 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 (SELECT /*+ CARDINALITY(tab 10000) */ setmemberid FROM tab WHERE uuid = '7C06216F-EFC8-418A-A6D9-77C7F6FE7AB1') fsq1 
 ON pat.pcpid = fsq1.setmemberid 
WHERE fsq1.setmemberid IS NULL
) pat
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((pat.bval1), (pat.bval2), ())
;
```

If I remove the CARDINALITY hint query works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got a workaround from Oracle:

```
/*+ opt_param('_simple_view_merging', 'false') */
```

or

```
alter session set "_simple_view_merging"=false;
```

So the following query works:

```
SELECT COUNT(patientId) n FROM (
SELECT /*+ opt_param('_simple_view_merging', 'false') */ DISTINCT pat.patientId, pat.bval1, pat.bval2
FROM pat
 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 (SELECT /*+ CARDINALITY(tab 10000) */ setmemberid FROM tab WHERE uuid = '7C06216F-EFC8-418A-A6D9-77C7F6FE7AB1') fsq1 
 ON pat.pcpid = fsq1.setmemberid 
WHERE fsq1.setmemberid IS NULL
) pat
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((pat.bval1), (pat.bval2), ())
;
```